# How to upload file using PHP on Synology NAS / FTP Server?

Tags: php, curl, file-upload, ftp

I want to make a file and upload that on Synology NAS using PHP. Our NAS, it's support FTP so i tried to use ftp_put() from [here](https://www.codexworld.com/connect-ftp-server-upload-download-delete-file-php/) and tried to use curl() from [here](http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/tutorial-ftp-upload-via-curl/). But i still cannot upload the file to NAS. 
Both of that code is running well and doesn't show the message error.

Here's the destination path on our Synology NAS : **/DMS/upload-file/**

And here's my simple code using ftp_put():

```
$ftp_path = '/DMS/upload-file/'.$_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"];
$conn_id = ftp_ssl_connect($host,$port);
$login_result = ftp_login ( $conn_id , $username , $password );
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $ftp_path, $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"], FTP_ASCII);
print (!$upload) ? $bgalert.'There was a problem while uploading '.$ftp_path.'</p>' : $bgalert.'Upload complete</p>';
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

The result always

> There was a problem while uploading
>   /DMS/upload-file/filename.jpg

Can anyone help me how to fix our problem ? I really need your help.
Thank you.

Comment: Can't you upload files using filezilla?

Comment: @TYPO3User Yes i can upload files using filezilla

Comment: can you show be about $ftp_path value and result of login ($login_result)

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this folder permission /DMS/upload-file/ ?

Comment: the all folder have 777 permissions.

Comment: Is your your ftp user have permission to create, updated and delete that directory?
As i know, NAS used acl to that.

Comment: yes, the ftp user have permission for CRUD. I tried to using that account on ftp client suck as filezilla. The problem only in PHP.